# Add separate UINavigationController to child class

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

How to add my own UInavigationController to child class.

Here is my code

```
    VC1 *vController  = [[VC1 alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:YES];

[vController release];
```

I need to add one more navigationcontroller to **vController** . so I can maintain separate stack for child.

I tried this way but it did not work for me.

```
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
  [self.view addsubview:navController.view];

[navController release];
```

it is overlapping on parent navigationController.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jamie hi, I am trying to maintain separate stack for VC1 till now i did not get required answer for me. If you have any idea or suggestion please help me

Comment: Is your problem that two NavigationBars appear? The main one, and then the new one underneath it?

Comment: @jamie parent one should disappear only child navigationController should appear

Comment: if that is really what you want to do then you have to tell the parent navcon to hide. but it looks awful when it animates, so then you have to turn animation off, and that looks bad too. thing is, maybe a tab view is a better way to manage multiple stacks?

Comment: Thanks to all, I sort out problem by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have "A" Main Navigation controller & B controller whether inherited by TableView or anything.

Create object of UINavigationController in B . Create object of B in A like B *bObject. Pass self.navigationControl to B like

```
bObject.navgationObject=self.navigationController
```

and access all navigation with navgationObject in B. Not need to call self.navigation in B just use navgationObject.

I hope this is ur answer

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
VC1 *vController  = [[VC1 alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navController= [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController:vController];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[vController release];
```

It's modal, so to remove it you're going to need a reference to the parent `navigationController` to dismiss the child navigation controller.